# Imgur.com does not load due to HTTPS settings

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dns, internet-explorer, ssl

For some reason I am having some issues when I try to load imgur.com links sometimes. Here is a screenshot of what I see

[image]

Whats strange is that it I get a 404 from Google and not Imgur (I am using google's 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 DNS though). This issue comes and goes and sometimes when this issue is persisting, I get a SSL error saying `"This server could not prove that it is imgur.com; its security certificate is from appspot.com"`

This is not an issue with just Chrome.. it persists between all my browsers (FF/IE)

What could be causing this?

Edit: here is a screenshot of the nslookup and ping commands

[image]

Comment: Looks like your HTTP(S) traffic is being hijacked. How are you connected to the Internet? Are you using a proxy? Is that your own private network, or is it controlled by someone else?

Comment: It's my own private network. No vpn or proxy

Comment: Can you run these two commands in command line and include results (you can [edit] your question)? `nslookup i.imgur.com` and `ping i.imgur.com`

Comment: Well right now the problem fixed itself (but it will be back like it usually does)